# How to camouflage the IP packages in a Home share wireless router?

Tags: wireless

I want to be able to hide my IP packages at best connecting to my router that I am sharing with other people in my house.

Is it possible? 
Can I encapsulate them and let them unreadable?

Comment: [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network), [SSH Tunnelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol#Secure_shell_tunneling), [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/), ...

Comment: @Francesco - you may notice your questions are getting a lot of downvotes. If this continues, you may find yourself suspended automatically. Please read the [faq] and [about] pages for guidance on how to ask questions, including doing the basic research first.

Answer (score 0):

Packages? Are you meaning packets?

If so, I am going to assume in my answer that you are talking about the communication on your internal household network, and not coming in from and external net into your home. If I am wrong, I apologize, but the scenario you describe seems to indicate that.

So the best way to "hide" your packets (i.e., keep secure from other's eyes on the same net) would be to use a VPN to your device. There are two ways you could accomplish that:

1. You could see if your device has a VPN option and if you have access and the rights to set that up, set up a VPN connection between your machine and the router. This would mean that traffic between you--->router would be encrypted, then outbound from there would be normal.
2. Google "vpn services". There are several paid external VPN services you can purchase that allow you to accomplish the same thing to a gateway they provide. Therefore you would have encrypted traffic (and an anonymous IP - typically) from you--->your router---->their gateway... Then from there would be normal.

Either of these should suffice.

I am assuming that you are concerned that some of your "roommates" are sniffing your traffic? Remember most HTTPS connections are encrypted, so banking, gmail, etc are not going to be "readable". Granted, it is weird, and they can start cracking the eggshell with little, non-secure leaks that might allow them to perform an MiTM attack later. But if you really have that serious of a concern, maybe you should move?

Comment: Packets yes : ) sorry for my English !

Answer (score 0):

Google "The Onion Project" (TOR) as this will do what you are wanting to.